# Should one specify a type signature for main or not? Why / why not?

Tags: haskell, program-entry-point, conventions, compiler-flags, type-signature

I learned from [chapter 9 of Learn You A Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#hello-world) that

> By convention, we don't usually specify a type declaration for `main`.

As far as I can tell, this convention is widespread. However, if I compile, using the `-Wall` flag, a program that lacks a type signature for `main`, such as

```hs
-- test.hs

-- main :: IO ()
main = print (1 :: Int)
```

GHC does issue a warning:

```
$ ghc -Wall test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:2:1: Warning:
    Top-level binding with no type signature: main :: IO ()
Linking test ...
$
```

I'm confused... If a type signature for `main` is indeed superfluous, why would `-Wall` cause GHC to complain when it's missing? Are there good reasons (aside from getting rid of that warning) for specifying `main`'s type anyway?

Comment: Missing top level type signature should be an error. In fact it should be illegal.

Comment: Illegal as in should be punishable as a crime. Not illegal in the language.

Comment: In particular, top-level *exported* type signature could be an error. I use a lot of very generic helpers that aren't exported, don't have public docs and their signatures are longer than their bodies. Writing those out doesn't help at all and is just an annoyance.

Comment: The book is merely stating that they are not going to provide type annotations for `main` to reduce clutter in their presentation. They are not implying that you should not annotate it.

Comment: @chi Interesting; I didn't read it in that way. I'm not sure which way that sentence is supposed to be interpreted, though. Another instance of an ambiguous "we".

Comment: I also get the impression that the sentence is talking about a convention used in the book and not about the Haskell community in general. I've personally found that giving `main` an explicit type signature is very useful in practice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, generally speaking, as that warning makes clear, it's *always* a good idea to give top-level bindings a type signature. In fact, it would be more reasonable to say

> By convention, we do specify a type declaration for **everything**<sup>1</sup>.

Certainly, in a big project, `main` itself makes up a neglectable effort, so it really doesn't make any sense to omit the signature. Just write it out, for sake of consistency.

However, though Haskell is great for properly structured projects and actually there's a tendency to write almost everything in *libraries*, it's also surprisingly good as a quick scripting language, for stuff other people would write in Python or Perl. And in those cases, you generally don't care that much about safety and good documentation etc., you just want to quickly write down something as concise as possible that does the job. You also normally don't compile those scripts with `-Wall` but just execute them with `runhaskell`. And as scripts always need to contain a `main` (unlike most other Haskell source files), it is indeed sensible enough to omit the signature here.

I'd still suspect that the majority of Haskellers nowadays *do* write `main::IO()` even in the simplest scripts, if just out of habit.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Only everything on the top-level, that is. Local signatures sometimes do make sense as well, but often they rather clutter the code.</sub>

Comment: Also for bigger projects it makes sense to enable `-fwarn-missing-signatures` and `-Werror`, which then forces `main` to have a type signature.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I typically use `-Wall` (which enables `-fwarn-missing-signatures`, I believe) in conjunction with `-Werror`.

Answer (score 8):

It's actually a very good idea to write a type signature for `main`, since otherwise if you get too fancy trying to write things in point-free form, you can end up with `main` of type `IO (IO ())`. This is accepted (the language standard says `main` just has to have some type of the form `IO a`) but the "inner IO action" that is the result of `main` will just be discarded, which is almost certainly not what you wanted (you probably wanted to `join` it).

Comment: Interesting. Could you add a link to where, in the standard, you read that *`main` just has to have some type of the form `IO a`*?

Comment: @Jubobs: see the second paragraph of https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-980005

Comment: I'd argue that not requiring `main :: IO ()` is a (very) minor defect of the standard. This is however a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Could you add such an example when `main` ends up with `IO (IO a)`?

Comment: @PetrPudlák A contrived example: `main = return getLine`, which is of type `IO (IO String)`.

Comment: Or slightly less contrived, `main = putStrLn <$> getLine`.